# Origen del vocablo "orientar"

Tags: etimología, historia

La etimología de orientar apunta al término *oriente*, según observo en [este sitio](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?orientar), aunque por lo visto el vocablo no aparece en el diccionario de la RAE hasta 1884 y su uso previo, según google ngrams es ocasional los 3 siglos previos a su aparición (entre 1600 y 1900 aparece en algunos años). Al parecer la palabra tiene su origen en latín (*oriens*) pero entonces, ¿Por qué su uso ocasional? ¿Desde cuando se usa en español?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corominas establece el origen de palabras como *orientar*, *oriental* y la misma *oriente* en el término *origen*, derivado en última instancia de *oriri* 'salir (los astros)'. La voz *oriente* viene del participio presente *oriens, -tis*, 'que está saliendo (el sol)'. Corominas aclara también que todas estas voces son cultismos (aunque en el caso de *origen*, esta es ampliamente usada).

Aunque la voz *orientar* no aparece en el DLE hasta el siglo XIX, se puede encontrar una aparición antes en el diccionario de Terreros y Pando de 1787:

> ORIENTAR, volver alguna cosa hácia el Oriente.

Nótese que se usaba este verbo porque *oriente* era, ya según el *Autoridades* de 1737:

> ORIENTE. [...] el primero de los quatro Puntos Cardinales en que se divide la Esphera.

Igual que ahora tomamos el norte como el primer punto cardinal, antes lo era el oriente, dado que lo más fácil era orientarse según la dirección por la que sale el sol. En todo caso, aunque *oriente* es antigua, su derivado verbal es bastante más moderno. La entrada arriba expuesta de Terreros y Pando nos da una idea de cuando surgió el verbo, al igual que esta copla de la misma época:

> *La moda en nuestro idioma
>
>   aun los verbos ha trocado,
>
>   pues por decir "ya lo entiendo",
>
>   dicen "Ya estoy orientado".*
>
> Anónimo, "El nuevo diccionario. Tonadilla a solo", 1795 (España).

En la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España los primeros casos de palabras como *orientarse* u *orientado* son de la década de 1780. Por tanto podemos pues establecer un origen del verbo por esa época.

Comment: En los mapas cristianos medievales el oriente estaba en la parte superior de los mapas, y habitualmente ponían ahí el Edén.